# How do I get the photo filenames from my LX5 to continue from a given number?

Tags: memory-card, panasonic, filenames, file-management

I have a lovely new Panasonic LX5, replacing my LX3. I am using the same SD card as in the LX3, which already has the folders 100, 101, 102, ... 116 (yes, that was a thousand photos per folder...).

The manual seems to imply that the new camera would continue with photos starting with 1170000.jpg; however, it has started at 1000000.jpg, and is blithely placing the new photos mixed up with the occasional old one into the existing folders. So I will have every filename twice on my pc, unless I rename all the old files - something I have no intention of doing.

How can I get the new camera to start numbering its files with a later number? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm glad it worked out for you. I'm not sure what exactly made it decide to continue from the number the third time — it's always creepy when software behaves non-deterministically.

I know you said you didn't want to rename your old files, but I find it really convenient to do so. There are a number of free (open source and otherwise) cross-platform programs which will do it for you systematically based on the EXIF metadata in the image files. I use [jhead](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/), with the options

```
jhead -autorot -nf%Y%m%d-%f *
```

Which losslessly rotates the images based on the embedded rotation flag and then prefixes them with a date-based filename.

Answer (score 0):

Hah - the third time I put the SD card in, it **did** start numbering the pictures starting at 1170000. So I guess the answer is "keep trying". I will leave the question in case someone has a method of changing the number which is more general.